Search which groups is the AD user member of
I need to authorize the user in AD and receive the list of groups which is the user member of. I have done the code working, but the search takes very long - about 20 seconds in my small office AD with 10 users and 10 groups. It is not about network timeouts, login happens in milliseconds. I have found that it is exactly the conn.search_s() line which is so slow. Do you have any ideas how to improve performance? I think it should search under one second over LAN in so small database... Thanks a lot!
import ldap

BIND_ADDRESS = "192.168.0.1"
USERNAME = "my.name@mydomain.local"
PASSWORD = "myPassword"
LDAP_BASE = "dc=mydomain,dc=local"

conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://" + BIND_ADDRESS + ":389")
conn.simple_bind_s(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

result = conn.search_s(LDAP_BASE,
                          ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                          'userPrincipalName='+USERNAME,
                          ['memberOf'])
print(result)
conn.unbind_s()


The problem was that the Active Directory contains many more structures then  Users and Groups and the code above is searching everywhere.
I have solve it by adding "cn=Users" to the LDAP base, this makes it searching only in "user LDAP space":
LDAP_BASE = "cn=Users, dc=mydomain,dc=local"

The complete working code with result parsers looks like that:
import ldap

BIND_ADDRESS = "192.168.0.1"
USERNAME = "my.name@mydomain.local"
PASSWORD = "myPassword"
LDAP_BASE = "cn=Users, dc=mydomain,dc=local"

conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://" + BIND_ADDRESS + ":389")
conn.simple_bind_s(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

result = conn.search_s(LDAP_BASE,
                          ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                          'userPrincipalName='+USERNAME,
                          ['memberOf'])
result = result[0][1]["memberOf"]

groups = []
for i in result:
    group = i.decode("utf-8").split(",", 1)[0].replace("CN=", "")
    groups.append(group)

print(groups)

conn.unbind_s()

